# Python rpi.GPIO with Snapcraft / snap?

Tags: python, packaging, snap, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I'm having great trouble trying to build a snap for a simple python code for Rpi2.

Code I would like to put into a Snap is:

```
# External module imports
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

print("Hello LED")

ledPin = 9

print("Setting Broadcom Mode")
# Pin Setup:
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # Broadcom pin-numbering scheme

GPIO.setup(ledPin, GPIO.OUT) 

print("Here we go! Press CTRL+C to exit")
try:
while 1:
        print ("OFF");
        GPIO.output(ledPin, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(1.00)
        print ("ON");            
        GPIO.output(ledPin, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(1) 
except KeyboardInterrupt: # If CTRL+C is pressed, exit cleanly:
   GPIO.cleanup() # cleanup all GPIO
```

The thing is that I don't seem to find in the documentation how to import rpi.GPIO **Is this even possible?**

Searched in https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen with no results

Thats the hard question. Easier question is.. How do I execute a python script with a snap? I tried putting in:

```
apps:
  helloLed:
      command: sudo python helloLed.py
```

and without the `sudo`, after it triggered error for permission.

Thank you in advance! Will be posting full example tutorial when complete!

Comment: You need to include RPi.GPIO in your snap, perhaps with a requirements.txt.

Answer (score 0):

Add it using Python3 plugin, OP included partial `snapcraft.yaml`, may be need only an edit:

```
...
parts:
  plugin: python3
  python-packages:
    - RPi.GPIO
...
```

Also it needs an access interface:

```
...
apps:
  ...
  plugs:
    - physical-memory-control
...
```

Then after installation the user should connect it, because that interface is not `auto`

```
sudo snap connect helloLed:physical-memory-control
```

**Reference:** [Your first robot: Sharing with others [5/5]](https://snapcraft.io/blog/your-first-robot-sharing-with-others-5-5)

***Note***

I still have some doubts: if `RPi.GPIO` building from source needed. If that was the case, that it should be declared in `snapcraft.yaml` as a part. See the linked reference.